# How to change the sender email address that is used by iCal for sending "Accept Invitation"?

Tags: icloud, mail.app, email, calendar, ical

I have setup multiple email addresses on my Macs (business 1, business 2, privat, business 3 and so on).

However, when I receive a calendar event invitation by email, and click on "accept", the reply is sent with a wrong Email address, that I have used years ago, but not yet any more.

I even don't use iCal with this particular old email-address anymore, so it won't show up on the calendar accounts list.

The "show my card" feature in Contact, which is frequently mentioned as the sender address for such cases, displays my current mail address ("business 1"), where I receive all these invitations.

However, any action on my side like "Accept invitation" will still be send with an old address.

How can I change this?